# C# Non standard header in response causes exception

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, http-headers, httpclient

I have to be able to send a HTTP request for a response like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
/bin/sh: check_updatelock: not found
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: ...
Content-Type: application/json

{"response": "..."}
```

Now here `/bin/sh` causes exception: `Received an invalid header name: '/bin/sh'` (at `System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ParseHeaderNameValue`).
I've tried with `HttpClient`, `WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest`, and even with a 3rd party lib named `Flurl`, but that uses `HttpClient` under the hood.
The result is always the same expection.
Even in PowerShell, with `Invoke-WebRequest`, there is an execption: `The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=Header name is invalid`

How could I read such a response from a C# .NET Core console app?
(The server is out of my control)

Any idea highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Separator chars, like '/', are not part of the field name in the header. So HttpClient (and other libraries built on top of it) will throw an error.

You can try other third party libraries, which are not based on HttpClient like [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) (I'm not sure whether it supports non-standard header, but its not based on HttpClient)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Tried it, the same with it: `Received an invalid header name: '/bin/sh'.` I guess at some point, this lib also calls for the same code as `HttpClient` does. Do you know of another 3rd party libs which are not HttpClient based?

Comment: Sorry, no other libraries that I know of :-(